# GTK++/Cairo: load png, rotate, and copy rectangle to surface

Tags: rotation, copy, cairo, surface

I am in the process of developing an artificial horizon, as used in planes. This horizon has a background containing ground (brown) and sky (blue). Depending on the roll-angle/pitch of the plane, this background is rotated.

In order to keep it simple and keep CPU usage low, instead of drawing everything every pass, I wish to use an oversized static background image, which I will rotate as needed, and from which I will then copy/paste a square section to the screen.

The problem I'm having, is that I can't get cairo to rotate the surface FIRST and THEN copy/paste a section. It does copy/paste correctly, only rotates AFTER this has been done.

The code I have so far:

```
#define WINDOW_WIDTH  320
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 240


double deg2rad( double degrees )
{
     return((double)((double)degrees * ( (double)M_PI/(double)180.0 ))); 
}

static gboolean draw_cb(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data) 
{
     cairo_surface_t *source;
     cairo_t *bck;
     cairo_pattern_t *source_pattern;
     gint s_width, s_height, d_width, d_height,source_x, source_y;

     // load the image from disk
     source = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png ("/home/henri/dev/art_horiz_bck.png");
     bck = cairo_create(source);
     cairo_set_source_surface (bck, source,0,0);

     s_width = cairo_image_surface_get_width(source);
     s_height = cairo_image_surface_get_height(source);

     // rotate around center of image
     cairo_translate(bck, s_width/2, s_height/2);
     cairo_rotate(cr, deg2rad(30));
     cairo_paint(bck);

     // after rotation, the image size should have been changed (increased)

     s_width = cairo_image_surface_get_width(cairo_get_target (bck));
     s_height = cairo_image_surface_get_height(cairo_get_target (bck));

     d_width = gtk_widget_get_allocated_width (widget);
     d_height = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height (widget);

     // get the center 'viewport'
     source_x = (s_width/2)-(d_width/2);
     source_y = (s_height/2)-(d_height/2);

     // copy this rectangle to the destination surface

     cairo_set_source_surface (cr, source, -source_x, -source_y);
     cairo_rectangle (cr, 0, 0, 320, 200);
     cairo_fill (cr);

    return FALSE;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *grid;
    GtkWidget *topbar;
    GtkWidget *bottombar;
     GtkWidget *da;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    topbar = gtk_image_new_from_file ("/home/henri/dev/topbar.png");
    bottombar = gtk_image_new_from_file ("/home/henri/dev/bottombar.png");

    da = gtk_drawing_area_new();
    gtk_widget_set_size_request (da, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);


    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW (window), 0);
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    g_signal_connect (da, "draw", G_CALLBACK(draw_cb),  NULL);
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    grid = gtk_grid_new ();

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), grid);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), topbar, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), da, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), bottombar, 0, 2, 1, 1);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);



    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

As stated, this almost does what I want, besides the rotation not getting applied at cairo_paint(bck). So i FIRST want cairo to rotate the image and THEN get a square horizontal rectangle from it. Now it first gets the rectangle, and then rotates this.

//edit
to make this more clear. The app will run on an embedded device with a 320x240 tft screen. It will be fullscreen. Above and below the horizon windows there wil be small static bars. This question only handles the drawing area in between.

I have this background image:
http://s10.postimg.org/3xuvr2dyh/art_horiz_bck.png

This is sufficiently oversized to cover all possible roll and pitch angles of the airplane in question. Now suppose the plane is flying in a 10 degree nose up attitude (so it's climbing) and is rolling with 5 degrees roll-angle.

Now what I want to do is to rotate the above background by 5 degrees, and then take a rectangular section out of it, above the horizon, so that the 10 degree nose up attitude is also displayed. So from the above image, I want to distill this image:

http://s9.postimg.org/a4u8m4oan/Naamloos.png

Note that this second image is cropped to 320x240, the size of the drawing area it will be drawn on.

//edit 2
the below posted code by Uli Schlachter does seem to do what I want, however, goes wrong at this point:

```
cairo_matrix_translate (&matrix, -(s_width-d_width)/2.0, -(s_height - d_height)/2.0)
```

This is because it uses the dimensions of the original, unrotated image. I need it to use the dimensions of the already rotated image there.

Comment: You are drawing a surface to itself. That's not supported by cairo. If you want to do that, you need a temporary surface (however, that seems pointless here).

Comment: I am not drawing a surface to itself. I am using a temporary surface. However, cairo also needs a cairo_t for the rotate function. Please look at the code better, then you'll see I'm not drawwing a surface to itself.

Note that the first cairo_set_source_surface paints the surface to the temporary cairo_t called BCK. The second set source surface paints the surface of bck to cr. So no drawing to itself ;)

Comment: To quote the source: bck = cairo_create(source); cairo_set_source_surface(bck, source, 0, 0) The cairo context "bck" now paints to "source" and uses "source" as its, well, source. A little later you then call cairo_paint(bck) without changing the source in between. So yes, you are drawing a surface to itself.

Comment: Perhaps a clarification: cairo_rotate() by itself does not rotate anything. It just changes the coordinate system so that following code has rotation applied. Since the code from the question only does a cairo_paint(bck), nothing is actually rotated... I think

Comment: I know that the rotate itself doesn't do anything, however, as I understood it, the cairo_paint instruction will cause cairo to apply all transformations. If you do that paint to cr at that point, it will display a rotated image. The problem I'm having, is to get the bounding box size after the rotation.

Comment: cairo_paint() does not change the bounds of the image. The image is still the same. However, you *are* painting an image to itself with this paint, which is not allowed.

Comment: I really appreciate you helping me, but you're wrong. First of, cairo_create(source) does not paint anything. Try it yourself. It does not. Second of all, after having done that, I apply the rotation on it, BEFORE i call paint. So I'm not painting a surface to itself. At the most, I'm painting a rotated source to itself. However, that part of the code is working fine. It gives me the rotated image surface on bck.

Answer (score 1):

No idea if this works the way you want, but hopefully it helps you to figure out how to do what you want:

```
static gboolean draw_cb(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data) 
{
     cairo_surface_t *source;
     cairo_t *bck;
     cairo_pattern_t *source_pattern;
     gint s_width, s_height, d_width, d_height,source_x, source_y;
     cairo_matrix_t matrix;

     // load the image from disk
     source = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png ("/home/henri/dev/art_horiz_bck.png");
     source_pattern = cairo_pattern_create_for_surface (source);

     s_width = cairo_image_surface_get_width(source);
     s_height = cairo_image_surface_get_height(source);
     d_width = gtk_widget_get_allocated_width (widget);
     d_height = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height (widget);

     cairo_surface_destroy (source);

     // rotate around center of image
     cairo_matrix_init_identity (&matrix)
     cairo_matrix_translate (&matrix, s_width/2.0, s_height/2.0)
     cairo_matrix_rotate (&matrix, deg2rad(30));
     cairo_matrix_translate (&matrix, -(s_width-d_width)/2.0, -(s_height-d_height)/2.0)
     cairo_pattern_set_matrix (source_pattern, &matrix);

     // copy this rectangle to the destination surface
     cairo_set_source (cr, source_pattern);
     cairo_pattern_destroy (source_pattern);

     cairo_rectangle (cr, 0, 0, 320, 200);
     cairo_fill (cr);

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does seem to do something different than my original code, however, I have no idea what it actually does and I'm having trouble interpreting it's output.

I'll try to make some pictures to make more clear what it is I actually want to do.. please bare with me.

Comment: Please also see my edits to my question for clarification. However, I suspect your code might just do what I want, but is not centering correctly, ie, it's copy/pasting the wrong part. I will experiment further with it.

Comment: After some experimentation, I come to the conclusion that your code does do what I want, however, it does not center correctly. This is because it uses the original image sizes for copying the rectangle, not correcting for the fact that the source image has become bigger by rotating it. So i need this line: 
[code]
    cairo_matrix_translate (&matrix, -(s_width-d_width)/2.0, -(s_height-d_height)/2.0) 
[/code]
to not take the s_width, s_height from the original image, but from the already rotated image.

Comment: I would suggest to experiment with another image. This horizont is nice for the final product, but it might make sense to use something where you can actually see which part of your image is drawn where.